# Keep instance of Rscript open?

Tags: c++, r

Currently I am calling an R script from C++ in the following way:

```
system("PATH C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\x64");
system("RScript CommandTest.R");
```

Where CommandTest.R is my script.

This works, but is slow, since I need a particular package and this method makes the package load on every call.

Is there a way to load the package once and then keep that instance of Rscript open so that I can continue to make calls to it without having to reload the package every time?

PS: I know that the 'better' method is probably to go with Rcpp/Rinside, and I will go down that route if necessary, but I thought it'd be worth asking if there's an easy way to do what I need without it.

Comment: What you want is exactly what Rinside is for.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the [Rserve](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/Rserve/index.html) package is what you seek. Basically it keeps open a "server" which can be asked to evaluate expressions.

It has options for Java, C++ and communication between one R session and another.

In the [documentation](http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/web/packages/Rserve/Rserve.pdf), you might want to look at `run.Rserve` and `self.ctrlEval`

Comment: I've had a look at Rserve and tried to get it functioning, but I'm having problems with it. I also think it's a bit beyond my technical capabilities at the moment. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a solution to keeping R permanently open, but you can speed up startup by calling R with the `--vanilla` option.  (See Appendix B.1 of Intro to R for more options.)

You could also try accessing the functions using `::` to save completely loading the package.  (Try profiling to see if that really saves you much time.  Is the package load actually the slow part of your analysis?)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried --vanilla but it didn't make much difference. I had a look also at the package load and identified the major time sink is not actually that, but instead loading an object into the workspace. The question is still the same though, if there was a way to leave the workspace up so I only have to load that object once, it would be much, much faster.

Comment: How are you loading the object?  Is it via `load` or `readRDS` or `data`, or some other method?

Comment: I use the load method.

Comment: OK, in that case there isn't much you can do go speed it up.  Go with `Rinside` or `Rserve`.